# No triple loop with Touch + date

Tags: shell, loops, file, touch

I`m trying to create many files with older dates between 2014 and 2017 and they should all be inside some test folders.
So I created a script with some FOR loops and TOUCH.

```
#!/bin/bash

# LOOP DE ANO
for seqAno in $(seq 2014 2017); do

# LOOP DE 4 DIRETÓRIOS
        for seqDir in $(seq 4); do

# LOOP DE 100 ARQUIVOS
                for seqArq in $(seq 100); do
                        touch -d $seqAno'0102' /home/dan/teste/pasta$seqDir/arq$seqDir"_"$seqArq
                done

        done

done
```

The way it is, the script ends up with 2017 files only.
2014 to 2016 files are not being created.

```
root@Dan:/home/dan/teste# ll pasta1
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Mar  9 19:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Mar  9 19:08 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan  2  2017 arq1_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan  2  2017 arq1_10
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan  2  2017 arq1_100
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan  2  2017 arq1_11
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan  2  2017 arq1_12
...
```

Could anyone help out?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was making a logic error.

By the first year loop, It was creating files with a specific name and date.
By the second year loop, the same file name was being created, thus overwriting the existing file.

So, when it reached the last year loop, 2017, it overwrote the existing files again.

To solve that I just added *$seqAno* to the file name.

```
touch -d $seqAno'0102' /home/dan/teste/pasta$seqDir/arq$seqDir"_"$seqAno"_"$seqArq
```